# Why cant I see my navigation bar , everything is right

Tags: html, css, navigation, program-entry-point

I can't see the navigation bar even tho everything is right
Nothing is missing and its really getting frustrating now and I don't know what to do can someone help me please

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="topbar">

        </div>
        <nav id="main">

        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

```
 body{
     margin: 0;
 }
 header{
     background: url('./images/bg.png') bottom center no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 750px;
    
    }
     #topbar {
         height: 70px;
     }

      nav#main {
         height: 150px;
         color: white;
         border-radius: 4px;
        }
```

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please update the question to include all relevant code to demonstrate the problem.  For HTML/CSS/JS problems you can even include a runnable code snippet.  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What are you finding when you go to your browser's devtools inspect facility? It should be possible to see exactly what is covering or otherwise stopping your nav from being visible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `nav#main` you only applied `color:white` property so the `nav` is displayed and it is white in color . As also your `background-color` is not set so it is not visible .

So apply a `background-color` property . See below snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: url('./images/bg.png') bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 750px;
}

#topbar {
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#main {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#main a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#main a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="topbar">
      Hello
    </div>
    <nav id="main">
      <a>View</a>
      <a>Help</a>
      <a>Data</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is my html <html>

<head>
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="topbar">

        </div>
        <nav id="main">

        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Plz change question and enter complete code to it

Comment: Not only tags include your HTML & CSS complete

Comment: I included my html too

Comment: @AlexT `nav` is now visible brother . You can see in snippet

Comment: Anytime brother no worries .Is this answer acceptable brother . If yes can you accept it else no worries.

Comment: @AlexT a tick option will be available under the downvote option , just click it and it's color changes to green